# How to store files that have the same signature but contain different data using asp.net FileUpload control

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am using an ASP.NET `FileUpload` control to upload a file to a server and store it.

In my case, the uploaded file should have a `.doc` or `.docx` extension, otherwise it will provide an error message.

```
   if (fileUpload1.HasFile)
   {
       string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileUpload1.FileName);

       if (fileExtension.ToLower() == ".doc" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".docx")
       {
              fileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + fileUpload1.FileName));
              statusLabel.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully";
              statusLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
       }
       else
       {
              statusLabel.Text = "Only files with .doc or .docx extension are allowed!";
              statusLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
       }
}
```

When I upload a file and click upload button it will store it on the following directory of my project:

```
~/Uploads/
```

Suppose I upload a doc file (`test.docx`) that has some data. It will successfully be uploaded to the server and saved in the project directory ==>  `~/Uploads/`

But the problem is, when I again try to upload a file with the same signature (`test.docx`) but different contents, it uploads successfully but in the project `Uploads` directory the previous file will erased and only the newly file will present. But I want to keep both files.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Never use user input (like file name) for file name is OS. You can use any internal name, easiest like DateTime.UtcNow or Guid.NewGuid + you can map it to user's file name via database if you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lanorkin suggested you need to create a method to rename the file and then save it into the directory.

So in your code include the method to create a unique name for the file:

```
var FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName).Substring(1); 

fileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + "." + FileExtension);
```